# How to integrate Stockfish engine to Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to write an Android chess game with Stockfish engine. When I extract the folder that I downloaded I get two files named `stockfish-8-arm-v8a` and `stockfish-armeabi-v7a` but I have no clue how to use them. Any ideas?
Oh and i want to write my game using Unity.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, maybe you could provide more detail regarding your problem. check this link, help us to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: HI Codoral.  I would truly recommend you start with something simpler.  Also, such really general questions are not suitable for this site. *Perhaps* you could ask on gamedev, something like "how to integrate this sort of package to Unity".